# Elasticsearch: Master not discovered yet: have discovered <node> error

Tags: database, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have been facing an issue adding a new **Data node** to existing **single-node cluster**.
On the new node the service is successfully starting but couldn't join existing cluster with below errors are showing in the log.

`timed out while waiting for initial discovery state - timeout: 30`

`master not discovered yet: have discovered [{db3}...`

On the new node my **elasticsearch.yml** config is as follows,

```yaml
cluster.name: cluster_test

node.name: db3

network.host: 10.0.0.3

discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.0.0.1"]

cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.0.0.1"]

node.master: false

node.data: true
```

On the existing master node,

```
cluster.name: cluster_test

node.name: db1

network.host: 10.0.0.1

cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.0.0.1"]
```

Comment: Hey, this question need a bit more information. How are you deploying them ? docker ? Same host ? Please provide both master and data config.

Comment: using two different VM, i have updated above

Comment: initial_master_nodes contains node names, not ips. Try "db1".

Comment: @Jean-PierreMatsumoto  I tried these possibilities together `["10.0.0.1:9300","db1","db1.localdomain","10.0.0.1"]`

Comment: From the 2nd VM can you curl the master node ?

Comment: @Paulo You made my day! I tried curl form 2nd VM, but couldn't then I open port 9200 on master, then during the time i test curl new node was already added to cluster. Thanks very much for this light. But the curios thing is they say 9300 is the port using for communication between nodes, so i try opening this port before and even tried disabling firewall, why would disabling firewall couldn't allow the connection?